# Render HTML Tag Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am trying to add a render a template using the `push` mutation method. I want to push a section component, but instead of the template content I get the raw output of `<vsection></vsection'`. Can anyone help me render the actual template content and not the raw tags? I included a jsbin below.

http://jsbin.com/wurofatuve/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this a little oddly. What I think you'd be better off doing is putting a `v-for` on a `<vsection>` component.

```
<vsection v-for="section in sections">
  {{ section.content }}
</vsection>
```

This way, when you push content to `sections` it'll out put another one. You'll also have to adjust your section component so you can use the content.

```
<template id="section-template">
  <div class="section">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here it is working like I think you want: http://jsbin.com/suhadidobe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hey Bill, thank you for your reply, I didn't get a notification so sorry for the delay in response. Ultimately what I am trying to do is stack templates. So the user sees a list of buttons and when clicking a button that specific template will be added. I am going to try and make it work with what you provided. Thank you again for your response.